# Multiple post data to Mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with: I want to create admin for add questions to quiz system. Structure is:

```
<label>Question 1</label>
<input type='text' name='question' value=''/>  

<label>Possible reply</label>
<input type='text' name='1' /> 
<input type='text' name='2' />
...
<input type='text' name='6' />    
<label>**Correct reply</label>
<input type='text' name='correct' /> 


<label>Question 2 </label>
<input type='text' name='question' value=''/>     
<label>Possible reply </label>
<input type='text' name='1' /> 
<input type='text' name='2' />
...
<input type='text' name='6' />    
<label>Correct reply </label>
<input type='text' name='correct' />     

<label>Question 3 </label>
...
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
```

And I need multiple questions post to Mysql db tables: **question, 1,2,3,4,5,6, correct**.

I was create this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
$question  $_POST['question '];
$a = $_POST['1'];
$b = $_POST['2'];
$c = $_POST['3'];
$d = $_POST['4'];
$e = $_POST['5'];
$f = $_POST['6'];
correct = $_POST['correct '];

$result=mysql_query("insert into test (question, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, correct) values ('$result', '$a', '$b', '$c', '$d', '$e', '$f',  '$correct' )");
  }

else
{

?>
<label>Question 1 </label>
<input type='text' name='question' value=''/>  

<label>Possible reply </label>
<input type='text' name='1' /> 
<input type='text' name='2' />
...
<input type='text' name='6' />

<label>Correct reply </label>
<input type='text' name='correct' /> 


<label>Question 2 </label>
<input type='text' name='question' value=''/>  

<label>Possible reply </label>
<input type='text' name='1' /> 
<input type='text' name='2' />
...
<input type='text' name='6' />

<label>Correct reply </label>
<input type='text' name='correct' /> 


<label>Question 3 </label>
...
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>

<?         
}
```

But this send only 1 question to DB.

Comment: Please use mysql_real_escape_string() in order to prevent SQL injections!

Comment: yes, but i need help with sending questions to myslqDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use

```
<input type='text' name='question_1' value=''/>  
<input type='text' name='question_1' value=''/>  
<input type='text' name='question_1' value=''/>
```

Write in HTML:

```
<input type='text' name='question[]' value=''/>  
<input type='text' name='reply1[]' />  
<input type='text' name='reply2[]' />  
<input type='text' name='reply3[]' />  
<input type='text' name='reply4[]' />  
<input type='text' name='reply5[]' />  
<input type='text' name='reply6[]' />  
<input type='text' name='correct[]' />
```

In PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $questions=$_POST['question'];
    $reply1=$_POST['reply1'];
    $reply2=$_POST['reply2'];
    $reply3=$_POST['reply3'];
    $reply4=$_POST['reply4'];
    $reply5=$_POST['reply5'];
    $reply6=$_POST['reply6'];
    $correct=$_POST['correct'];
    foreach($questions as $key=>$value){
         $result=mysql_query("insert into test (question, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, correct) values ('$value', '".$reply1[$key]."', '".$reply2[$key]."', '".$reply3[$key]."', '".$reply4[$key]."', '".$reply5[$key]."', '".$reply5[$key]."',  '".$correct[$key]."' )");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you can state your database structure and expected result, because it may not work the way you think and we'll never know until we see it.

If you want 1 answer per row, you need to use a multiple row insertion - [How to insert multiple rows in single insert statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067113/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-in-single-insert-statement).

Answer (score 0):

try that:

> ```
> <input type='text' name='question1' value=''/>  
> <input type='text' name='question2' value=''/>
> ```

instead of

> ```
> <input type='text' name='question1' value=''/>     
> <input type='text' name='question1' value=''/>
> ```