# How can I insert multiple records with a single INSERT statement in Sybase ASE

Tags: sap-ase

This feature is available in [MySQL as shown in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067113/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-in-single-insert-statement) and according to the [Sybase documentation](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbreference/insert-statement.html) it should also be supported, however Sybase don't provide a worked example so you have to interpret the following:

***Syntax 1   Insert a single row, or multiple rows, with the specified expression column values. Multiple rows, if specified, are delimited by additional parentheses***

So I interpret "additional parentheses" as expecting the following code to work

```
create table #tmp_codes (
    code varchar(12) NULL
)

insert into #tmp_codes (code) 
values
    ('AAA'),
    ('BBB'),
    ('CCC')
```

However it errors with

```
Incorrect syntax near ',' on line 7
```

I'm using Sybase ASE 15 and cannot see any reference to inserting multiple rows [on this support page for the INSERT statement](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.commands/html/commands/commands62.htm)

Is this feature available in Sybase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first Sybase doc link is ASA not ASE documentation.
In ASE you can insert multiple rows only with insert - select statement.

Answer (score -1):

This seems long ago asked question but may be useful for reference.
Create a Text file with multiple Rows.

Run this command from Sybase ASE:

```
INPUT INTO TableName
FROM FilePath\FileName FORMAT TEXT
```

Example:

```
INPUT INTO TempTable FROM c:\test.txt FORMAT TEXT
```